# perform a TypeOrm find search operation for matching array of json

Tags: javascript, typescript, orm, typeorm

i have my typeorm column like this, what i want is an array of JSON object which i manage to get.

```
@Column({
    type: 'jsonb',
    array: false,
    default: () => "'[]'",
    nullable: false,
  })
  tokens!: Array<{ token: string }>;
```

[image]

this is how the field looks, and am fine with it, what i want is to find a document with a particular token, so i came up with the below code, but it returns an empty array.

```
const user = await User.find({ where: { _id: decoded._id, tokens: { token: token } } });
```

normally when am using mongooe i can get this working using

```
const user = await User.findOneBy({_id: decoded._id, "tokens.token": token,}); and this returns a particular user, with the id and token string passed.
```

i want help on how to find a user using the id and the token string inside in array of object, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

TypeORM does not natively support queries on PostreSQL `jsonb` columns. Performing a query on the data in a `jsonb` column would require you to either issue a raw query or write your own WHERE clause in`.where` or `.addWhere` of a query builder ([doc](https://typeorm.io/select-query-builder#adding-where-expression)).

For reference, the `jsonb` query syntax documentation can be found [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-json.html).